404 over this rollup-plugin ssh2
I tried this but its returning 404 error, as I am working on directus extension, I can't install npm install ssh2:
What I needed rollup for ssh: npm install rollup-plugin-ssh2, I have to install through rollup-plugin.
import { Client } from 'ssh2';
import fs from 'fs';

const conn = new Client();

        conn.on('ready', () => {
            console.log('Client :: ready');

            conn.shell(async (err, stream) => {
                if (err) throw err;
        
                stream.on('close', () => {
                    console.log('Stream :: close');
                    conn.end();
                });
        
                console.log("All data processed successfully");
            });
        }).connect({
            host: 'HOST_IP',
            username: 'USERNAME',
            privateKey: fs.readFileSync('/MyFile.pem')
        });

rollup-plugin-ssh2 correct way
